in pyspark, how do I reference another column when creating a new one? specifically in a struct?
I have a table where I want to create a new column where it takes the value of a column to parse through another column of structs. This is my table:



test
ALLSKY_KT




20010101
{"20010101":0.62}


20010101
{"20010101":0.62}


20010101
{"20010101":0.56}



The output that I want to see:



test
ALLSKY_KT
result




20010101
{"20010101":0.62}
0.62


20010101
{"20010101":0.62}
0.62


20010101
{"20010101":0.56}
0.56



I am trying this:

df.withColumn('result', col('ALLSKY_KT')[col('test')]))


but am getting this error:

[INVALID_EXTRACT_FIELD_TYPE] Field name should be a non-null string literal, but it's "test". SQLSTATE: 42000



Anyone have any thoughts to this?
